# Can Gitlab create a changelog based on merge requests

Tags: git, gitlab, versioning, changelog

For a project I want to be able to increase my version number and automatically generate a changelog entry every time I successfully merge a merge request on Gitlab. The entry should include the title of the MR.
There's a [Gitlab REST API endpoint](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#add-changelog-data-to-a-changelog-file) that generates a changelog, that seems very useful. But it only works when one uses a [git trailer](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers) on a commit. Instead, I want it to work with my merge requests. Like the following:

- merge a merge request
- a pipeline gets triggered, and sends a request to Gitlab API
- Gitlab creates new version number, and adds missing MR titles to the changelog

How do I get Gitlab to perform the third list item here?